# Find if x is bigger than y using bitwise operator in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

If x > y, then this function will return 1, other wise return 0.

so far i have

```
int isitGreater(int x, int y) {

     return (((y+((~x)+1)) >> 31) & 1);
```

but it's not working.

Allowed ops: Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

I'm sure I have the logic right, if X - Y and I get a negative number, that means y > x , so therefore the 32nd bit is a 1, so I shift that bit to the right 31 times and then "and" it with "1".

edit: this does not work if x is negative, due to overflow. how can i fix this overflow problem without using conditional statements?

Comment: Homework tag is deprecated; don't use it on new questions.

Comment: Also, since it is homework: what operators you allowed to use? It feels like `+` would be cheating.

Comment: The string "isn't working" is not a built-in error message in C.

Comment: For what values isn't it working, and why do you think it isn't working?

Comment: This URL might help -  
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

Comment: might have something to do with x and y being negative values to start with?

Comment: It might, if you don't know which of two negative values is greater but your algorithm does.

Comment: (-2147483648[0x80000000],2147483647[0x7fffffff]) fail

Comment: @jaylopp So you wasted everyone's time because you didn't bother to note that it only failed for a corner case. Bad SO citizenry. Do better.

Comment: @nneonneo Since when `homework` is deprecated? What to use instead?

Comment: @qrdl: Since [last week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). Don't use anything instead; if the question is a bad question, flag it as such.

Comment: 'this does not work if x is negative, due to overflow.' No, that's wrong. It doesn't work if x is -2147483648 ... that's the only value that overflows.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine for me. Please submit a valid question.

Edit: Your algorithm will not work correctly if x is -2147483648 because -(-2147483648) (or, equivalently, ~(-2147483648)+1)  overflows.

Comment: error i have is: (-2147483648[0x80000000],2147483647[0x7fffffff]) fail

Comment: @Jim - Did you try negative numbers ?

Comment: @jaylopp That would have been extremely pertinent info for the question description.

Comment: @AndrewAnderson Yes. Did you?

Comment: @jaylopp Oh good grief, Jay. The negative of -2147483648 is -2147483648.

Comment: How should I go on fix the overflow error?

Comment: @jaylopp That's a different question. Do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take the 2's complement of: -2147483648[0x80000000].

Comment: how can i fix this problem without using "if"

Comment: Of course you can take its 2's complement ... it just yields the same value.